# Installing custom kernel in Ubuntu results in error

Tags: module, linux-kernel, operating-system

I am installing linux kernel 5.8.10 in my existing Ubuntu system.

After going all the steps. When I started to install modules by command `sudo make modules_install` , I found 2 errors.

I can't find any way to solve it. Please help if anyone familiar with this kind of errors.

Errors:

```
cp: cannot stat 'net/atm/atm.ko' : No such file or directory
make[1]: ***[scripts/Makefile.modinst:33: net/atm/atm.ko] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:1387: _modinst_] Error 2
```

Comment: It's unlikely that you need the atm module.  Did you use the existing Ubuntu config file?  Did you run `make oldconfig`?

Comment: No. I didn't run it.